# Why does the compiler keep giving "error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token"?

Tags: c

So I'm new to programming and specifically C programming and whilst I was making a program that would take data about an employ as input and put forth a modified salary, I ran into this error:

```
gcc /tmp/QbXFmvH0nL.c -lm
/tmp/QbXFmvH0nL.c:25:20: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
   25 | struct Emp_Dat_Inp() {
      |                    ^
```

The error arises when I define the function. The code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Emp_Data{ //defines a struct for employee data, instead of 
    int Emp_Salary;      //defining three seperate instances of variables
    int leaves;
    int Ext_Sal;
} empdat;

struct Emp_Data Emp_Dat_Inp();
//void Sal_Mod();
//void Tot_Sal();


int main()
{
    empdat Emp_1;
    Emp_1 = Emp_Dat_Inp();
    
/*    Sal_Mod();
      Tot_Sal();
*/    
}

struct Emp_Dat_Inp() {
    empdat Data;
    while(Data.Emp_Salary > 70000 || Data.Emp_Salary < 30000 )
    {
    printf("Please enter the employee salary:\n");
    printf("(NOTE: it must be within 30000 and 70000)");
    scanf("%d", &Data.Emp_Salary);
    }

    printf("Please enter the extra sales made:\n");
    scanf("%d", &Data.Ext_Sal);

    printf("Finally please enter the number of leaves taken:\n");
    scanf("%d", &Data.leaves);
    
    return Data;
}
```

What I can't understand is why is it asking for an identifier or '(' when I have put the left bracket?
Maybe it has something to do with the struct that I'm using?

Comment: What is the return type of that function? Hint: look at the forward declaration of that function.

Comment: Compare the function declaration and the function implementation. They should be the same.

Comment: Because of your question's title I'm tempted to answer "Because you keep doing the same error." ;-) SCNR.